# Behavior of function $\sum_{j = n}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi x)}{(2j-1)^2}$

Tags: limits, inequality, asymptotics, trigonometric-series

For a positive integer $n$, define the function
$$
F_n(x) = n^2 \sum_{j = n}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi x)}{(2j-1)^2}.
$$
I am trying to understand the behavior of $F_n(x)$ in the following sense. For a positive exponent $\alpha$, I would like to
compute the limit
$$
L_\alpha = \lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(1/n^\alpha). 
$$

Based on plotting in Mathematica, it appears that $L_\alpha$ has the following behavior: it seems to be $0$ for $\alpha > 2$, infinite for $\alpha < 2$ and some finite number for $\alpha = 2$.

I tried to simplify the summation but I am having difficulty passing to the limit.

Comment: Approximately what finite number do you get for $\alpha = 2$? Is it by any chance close to $\pi^2/4 \approx 2.467$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution.**

**Fact 1.** If $\alpha > 2$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(1/n^\alpha) = 0$.

**Fact 2.** If $1 < \alpha < 2$,
then $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(1/n^\alpha) = \infty$.

**Fact 3.** If $0 < \alpha \le 1$,
then $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(1/n^\alpha) = \infty$.

**Fact 4.** If $\alpha = 2$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(1/n^\alpha) = \frac{\pi^2}{4}$.

---

*Proof of Fact 1.*

Let $N := \lfloor n^\alpha \rfloor$. We have
\begin{align*}
 F_n(1/n^\alpha) &= n^2 \sum_{j = n}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &= n^2 \sum_{j = n}^{N} \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)}{(2j-1)^2} + n^2 \sum_{j = N + 1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &\le n^2 \sum_{j = n}^{N} \frac{\left((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha\right)^2}{(2j-1)^2} + n^2 \sum_{j = N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &\le n^2 \cdot N \cdot \left( \pi /n^\alpha\right)^2 + n^2 \sum_{j = N+1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{j-1} - \frac{1}{j}\right)\\
 &= n^2 \cdot N \cdot \left( \pi /n^\alpha\right)^2 + n^2 \cdot \frac{1}{N}\\
 &\to 0
\end{align*}
where we use $\sin^2 u \le u^2$ for all $u > 0$, and $\frac{1}{(2j-1)^2} \le \frac{1}{j^2} \le \frac{1}{(j-1)j} = \frac{1}{j-1} - \frac{1}{j}$ for all $j > 2$.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 2.*

For sufficiently large $n$, we have $M := \lfloor \frac14n^\alpha\rfloor > n$, and
\begin{align*}
 F_n(1/n^\alpha) &= n^2 \sum_{j = n}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &\ge n^2 \sum_{j = n}^{M} \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &\ge n^2 \sum_{j = n}^{M} 
 \frac{\frac{4}{\pi^2}\left((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha\right)^2}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &= n^2 (M - n + 1) \frac{4}{\pi^2}\left( \pi /n^\alpha\right)^2\\
 &\to \infty
\end{align*}
where we use $\sin^2 u \ge \frac{4}{\pi^2}u^2$ for all $u \in (0, \pi/2]$, and $(2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha \in (0, \pi/2]$ for all $j \in [n, M]$.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 3.*

We have
\begin{align*}
 F_n(1/n^\alpha) &= n^2 \sum_{j = n}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &\ge n^2 \sum_{j = n}^{2n} \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &\ge n^2 \sum_{j = n}^{2n} \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)}{(2\cdot 2n-1)^2}\\
 &= \frac{n^2}{(2\cdot 2n-1)^2} \sum_{j = n}^{2n} \sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)\\
 &= \frac{n^2}{(2\cdot 2n-1)^2} \sum_{j = n}^{2n} \frac12\Big(1 - \cos(2(2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)\Big)\\
 &= \frac{n^2(n+1)}{2(2\cdot 2n-1)^2} 
 - \frac{n^2}{2(2\cdot 2n-1)^2} \sum_{j = n}^{2n} \cos(2(2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha).
\end{align*}

Let $\beta := 2\pi /n^\alpha$. We have
\begin{align*}
 &\sum_{j = n}^{2n} \cos(2(2j-1) \pi /n^\alpha)\\
  ={}& \sum_{j=n}^{2n} \cos ((2j-1)\beta)\\
 ={}& \frac{\cos((3n + 1)\beta)\sin((n + 1)\beta)}{\sin \beta}
 + \cos ((2n-1)\beta) - \cos ((4n + 1)\beta)\\
 ={}& \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
  \cos \frac{2\pi}{n} & \alpha = 1 \\[6pt]
  O(n^\alpha) & 0 < \alpha < 1.
 \end{array}
 \right.
\end{align*}
Thus, $F_n(1/n^\alpha) \to \infty$.

$\phantom{2}$

*Proof of Fact 4.*

Let $N := n^2$. We have
\begin{align*}
 F_n(1/n^2) &= n^2 \sum_{j = n}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^2)}{(2j-1)^2}\\
 &= \frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\sum_{j = n}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^2)}{((2j-1) \pi /n^2)^2}\\
 &= \frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^2)}{((2j-1) \pi /n^2)^2} - \frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^2)}{((2j-1) \pi /n^2)^2}\\
 &= \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{2\pi}{n^2}\cdot \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^2)}{((2j-1) \pi /n^2)^2} - O(1/n)\\
 &= \frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{2\pi}{N}\cdot \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /N)}{((2j-1) \pi /N)^2} - O(1/n)\\
 &\to \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 y}{y^2}\mathrm{d} y\\
 &= \frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{align*}
where we use $\frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /n^2)}{((2j-1) \pi /n^2)^2}
\le \frac{\pi^2}{n^2}\sum_{j = 1}^{n-1} 1 = \frac{\pi^2}{n} = O(1/n)$,
and the fact that $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{2\pi}{N}\cdot \frac{\sin^2((2j-1) \pi /N)}{((2j-1) \pi /N)^2}$ is a Riemann Sum.

Comment: A similar proof works for $a<1$ and $a=1$ as in the first case using $2\sin^2 x =1-\cos 2x$ one easily shows that $\sum_{n \le k \le 2n}$ of the corresponding cosines is $o(n)$ by the first derivative test say so the partial sum there is $\Omega(n)$ while for $a=1$ the $\sin^2 >>c>0$ between $n$ and $2n$ anyway so the series is $>>cn$ there; the only case of interest is $a=2$ where the integral argument can be made rigorous

Comment: @Conrad Exactly! Before I saw your comment, I have exactly dealt with $0< \alpha \le 1$ , $\sum_{n \le k \le 2n}$ and also use $2\sin^2 x =1-\cos 2x$!

Comment: Thank you for carrying out such tedious computations.

Comment: @DrewBrady You are welcome. Actually, we can shorten the solution using the idea in the proof of Fact 4. But Facts 1-3 do not involve integral etc. (using inequality technique).

Answer (score 5):

This will be a partial answer, since I can't establish what happens when $\alpha<1$, and because I haven't been terribly rigorous in passing from the sum to the integral below. Perhaps someone else can fill in the gaps.

Assume $\alpha \geq 1$. Then:
\begin{align}
L_\alpha &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^2\sum_{j=n}^\infty {\left[\frac{\sin\bigl((2j-1)\pi/n^\alpha\bigr)}{2j-1}\right]}^2\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{2}\sum_{j=n}^\infty \frac{2}{n}{\left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n^{\alpha-1}}\,\frac{2j-1}{n}\right)}{\frac{2j-1}{n}}\right]}^2 \qquad\text{Riemann sum with $x = (2j-1)/n$}\\
&\rightarrow\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{2}\int_2^\infty {\left[\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n^{\alpha-1}}\,x\right)}{x}\right]}^2 dx\qquad\;\;\,\text{Change of variables $x = y n^{\alpha-1}$}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^{2-\alpha}}{2}\int_{2/n^{\alpha-1}}^\infty {\left[\frac{\sin\left(\pi\,y\right)}{y}\right]}^2 dy \qquad\;\;\;(1)\\
\end{align}
There are now two cases to consider:

$\bullet\;\alpha>1$

Here (1) becomes
\begin{align}
L_\alpha &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n^{2-\alpha}}{2}\int_0^\infty {\left[\frac{\sin\left(\pi\,y\right)}{y}\right]}^2 dy\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n^{2-\alpha}\;\frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{align}
Clearly this diverges for $1<\alpha<2$, goes to zero for $\alpha>2$, and goes to $\pi^2/4$ for $\alpha=2$.

$\bullet\;\alpha=1$

Here (1) becomes
\begin{equation}
L_\alpha = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n}{2}\int_2^\infty {\left[\frac{\sin\left(\pi\,y\right)}{y}\right]}^2 dy \rightarrow \infty
\end{equation}

I don't know what happens when $\alpha<1$ because in that case the Riemann sum above can't be simply written as the integral that follows it.

Comment: How do you justify that the summation converges to the integral you wrote down, since the function and the points you are evaluating both depend on $n$?

Comment: Upon further reflection, I've realized that the passage from sum to integral only "works" when $\alpha \geq 1$. I've edited the answer to reflect this. As for the justification, I convinced myself by plotting the points in the sum along with a graph of the smooth curve they approximate. I found that for large $n$ the points lie ever closer to the curve, and "fill" the curve ever more densely. Not terribly rigorous, I know, but I'm content for the above to be considered only a partial answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me verify the case $\alpha = 2$.

Using the identity $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \cos(2x))$ and the well known sum $\sum_{j = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2j-1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$, write
$$
\begin{align*}
n^{-2}F_n(x) &= \sum_{j = n}^\infty \frac{1}{2(2j-1)^2} - \sum_{j = n}^\infty\frac{\cos(2 \pi (2j - 1) x)}{2(2j-1)^2} \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{16} -\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2(2j-1)^2} -\sum_{j = n}^\infty\frac{\cos(2 \pi (2j - 1) x)}{2(2j-1)^2} \\
\end{align*}
$$
Now recall the Fourier series expansion of $|x|$ for $x \in (-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ :
$$
|x| = \frac{1}{4} - \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{2\cos(2\pi(2j-1)x)}{\pi^2(2j -1)^2}
$$
Substituting this in the above, we obtain
$$
\begin{align*}
n^{-2}F_n(x) &= \frac{\pi^2}{16} -\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2(2j-1)^2}+ \frac{\pi^2}{4}|x| -\frac{\pi^2}{16}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{\cos(2\pi(2j-1)x)}{2(2j -1)^2} \\
&=  \frac{\pi^2}{4}|x| -\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{1 -\cos(2\pi(2j-1)x)}{2(2j -1)^2} \\
\end{align*}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{align*}
F_n(n^{-2}) &= \frac{\pi^2}{4} -n^2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{1 -\cos(2\pi(2j-1) n^{-2})}{2(2j -1)^2}\\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{4} -n^2\sum_{j=1}^{2n-3} \frac{\sin^2(\pi j n^{-2})}{j^2}.
\end{align*}
$$

Denote $G(x):=\frac{\sin^2(\pi x)}{x^2}$, and notice that the last sum is $\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{j=1}^{2n-3} G(j/n^2)$.

Since $G$ is bounded,
$$
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j= 1}^{2n-3} G(j/n^2) \le C\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{2n-3}{n^2} = 0,
$$
Thus indeed
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} F_n(n^{-2}) = \frac{\pi^2}{4}.
$$
*Remark.* We have the formula
$$
F_n(n^{-\alpha}) = \frac{\pi^2}{4}n^{2-\alpha} - \frac{1}{n^{(2-2\alpha)}} \sum_{j=1}^{2n-3} G(j/n^{\alpha}) \le \frac{\pi^2}{4}n^{2-\alpha} ,
$$
from which the cases $\alpha > 2$, and $0 < \alpha \le 1$  follow easily.